# Android - not all logs appear in a logcat output

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat

I am using windows cmd terminal to output logs of my application using following command:

```
adb.exe logcat | find "%part_of_my_apps_name%"
```

however, not all logs appear in the output. Only messages like this one:

```
I/AppService(10597): Received start id 1: Intent { cmp=package_name/.AppService(has extras) }
```

And in my `AppService` I have the following code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    Log.i(TAG, "Test");
```

So what am I doing wrong?

**UPD**: I asked a bit wrong question. I actually used part of my app's name, not package, so it MUST appear in the log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a part of app's name, however, because `"find"` is basically `case sensitive` it did show me only that particular output ( name appeared in package name ) , so I came up with the following command:

```
adb.exe logcat -v time | find "%part_of_my_apps_name%" /I
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your `TAG` variable is, you use the command

```
adb.exe logcat -s "[tagname]"
```

For example if in my code, my TAG was declared as:

```
public static final String TAG = "com.myapp";
```

my LogCat would be

```
adb.exe logcat -s "com.myapp"
```

It also appears the quotes are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Logcat output is not associated with the `package name`, but with the string `TAG` you are using in your code. You could change all your tags to be your `package name`, or you could explicitly add your `package name` to the message in each `Log.i/w/e/v()` line, and then you will get the behavior you want. However, I would actually for with @A--C suggestion instead, as it allows you to have more granular filtering of the output of specific classes only.